# convert.im6: Unable to open image `xxx': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638

Tags: command-line, permissions, pdf, conversion

I just tried converting several different images into a PDF file using the 'convert' command in a terminal, but when I did so, it returned:

`convert.im6: Unable to open image 'xxx.pdf': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638`

where 'xxx.pdf' represents my output PDF file name. Of course, if I do it as root -- that is to say, `sudo convert` -- the operation goes through without a hitch. So my question, since I know some of you might probably say I'm an idiot for not thinking about doing the `sudo` act, is: Why is the `convert` command only available for root, instead of regular users? And is there any way I can change that?

Comment: How did you install ImageMagick and Ghostscript? Are you working on a read only mounted drive?

Answer (score 5):

Your suggestion is incorrect. Convert is available for all users.

If you're converting *into* a PDF and you're seeing `Unable to open image 'xxx.pdf'`, the program has tried to open `xxx.pdf` for writing and has been rebuffed by the Kernel because the current user can't write to that file. There are a couple of reasons:

- The current `$USER` can't write to the current directory. Try `touch testfile` and if that fails look at the directory permissions with `stat .`. To fix, either go to a directory where you *can* write, change the directory's permissions to allow $USER to write or change your user (eg add it to the right group) to allow it to write.

  There are various ACL options on top of this but it's most likely you're just in a root-controlled directory in which case just go somewhere else.
- There's already a file called `xxx.pdf` and it's owned by somebody else and `$USER` doesn't have write permission for it. Either `sudo chown $USER: xxx.pdf` (the `:` is not a typo), delete it and generate a new version from your `$USER`.

Both of these could be true at the same time.